# ModuleNotFoundError after pip install local python package

Tags: python

Structure:

```
.
├── application
│   └── runner.py
└── dummyLibrary
    ├── helperFunctions.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── setup.py
```

runner.py:

```
import dummyLibrary

dummyLibrary.foo()
dummyLibrary.bar()
```

**init**.py:
(empty file)

helperFunctions.py:

```
def foo():
    print("called foo()")


def bar():
    print("called bar()")
```

setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='dummyLibrary', version='0.0.1')
```

After cd'ing into dummyLibrary/ ,
I tried installing dummyLibrary with
pip3 install -e .
This was the output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Obtaining file:///home/ubuntu/Documents/pythonTest/dummyLibrary
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: dummyLibrary
  Running setup.py develop for dummyLibrary
Successfully installed dummyLibrary-0.0.1
```

I tried installing dummyLibrary with
python3 -m pip install -e .
This was the output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Obtaining file:///home/ubuntu/Documents/pythonTest/dummyLibrary
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: dummyLibrary
  Attempting uninstall: dummyLibrary
    Found existing installation: dummyLibrary 0.0.1
    Uninstalling dummyLibrary-0.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled dummyLibrary-0.0.1
  Running setup.py develop for dummyLibrary
Successfully installed dummyLibrary-0.0.1
```

After cd'ing into application/ and running
python3 runner.py
I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dummyLibrary
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dummyLibrary'
```

no matter how I try to install my library

**Why is this?**
Additional Information:
Using Ubuntu, Not using a virtual environment.
I tried rebooting after installing. Didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

First thing: `__init__.py` and `helperFunctions.py` should be inside another nested folder with the same name as the package.

```
.
├── application
│   └── runner.py
└── dummyLibrary
    ├── dummyLibrary
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── helperFunctions.py
    └── setup.py
```

Secondly, with the code in `runner.py` as how you'd like it, the `__init__.py` should include the following line to import all of the functions in `helperFunctions.py`:

```
from .helperFunctions import *
```

Finally, your `setup.py` should also include the parameter `packages` as a list of folder names in the package, in this case, the parameter should be `packages=['dummyLibrary']`.

P.S.: it's a pythonic practice to name your files and packages in `snake_case` rather than `camelCase`.